# string.Join() in .net 3.5

Tags: c#

I have a .net 3.5 project in vs2008 and I'm trying to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28VS.90%29.aspx) of `string.Join()` (the one that takes a `string` and `IEnumerable<T>`) and the compiler does not seem to know about this overload.

This is the code that I tried

```
    var result = string.Join(" ", Foo());
```

where `Foo()` is

```
    IEnumerable<string> Foo()
    {

        foreach(string s in new []{"1", "2", "3"} )
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
```

I get

```
> Error 2   Argument '2': cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'
```

Of course, if I use `Foo().ToArray()` it works but I'm wondering why the overload that takes `IEnumerable<T>` won't work.

MSDN in classic view says it's compatible with vs2008/.net 3.5

[image]

(I couldn't find the message "This page is specific to...." in non-classic views so I thought I'd put up a screen-cap.)

Comment: Er, [`String.Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) wasn't added until v4 (and subsequently in 4.5) -- **EDIT** To be clear, here are the [String Methods in 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The lightweight view doesn't have the "This page is specific to....".  Instead you select the version you want to see using a combo at the top of the page.

Comment: `Click to Rate and Give Feedback`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason string.Join needs to take an array instead of an IEnumerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968869/what-is-the-reason-string-join-needs-to-take-an-array-instead-of-an-ienumerable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version information at the bottom says something different:

[image: Version information on MSDN]

Note that you can find that version information at the bottom of the article, regardless of the selected view (it might just look a little different).

The note in the upper-right you have found is referring to the selected resource version you can find in the URL, such as in:

> `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876`**`(VS.90)`**`.aspx`

(highlighted in bold). Usually this selects the framework version as well (since those are released in tandem with VS), but apparently there seems to be a mistake in the classification here.

I'd just report it as a mistake.

Comment: There is a »Click to rate and give feedback« in the upper-right corner of the page. I'd use that to alert the maintaining team to this issue. In the lightweight version there is a »Feedback« link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 16):

The `string.Join` overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>` was not added until .NET 4. It is not available in .Net 3.5. The classic view in MSDN documentation is simply incorrect.

In .NET 3.5, you will need to invoke `ToArray()` on the `IEnumerable<string>` in order to pass it into the `Join` method.

```
string.Join(" ", Foo().ToArray());
```

For reference, [these are the overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) supported by .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the Supported Platforms section you can find out that:

> **NET Framework** 
>   Supported in: 4

So as a case use ToArray() along with Foo() call:

```
Foo().ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

The MDSN page you are looking at is only for .Net 4 and later. This is the page you should check:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c(v=VS.90).aspx

Notice that it specifically lists .Net Framework 3.5 and that it does not include your overload.

Answer (score 0):

The classic view does indeed provide a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28VS.90%29.aspx) to it, but it must be a wrong entry in their CMS or whatever. If you click the aforementioned link, you see that it's lost its context (the menu on the left does not know where you are, which should be in System.String.Join), and the version dropdown doesn't recognize it either.

The [normal version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) works, and shows it's only for .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.

> .NET Framework Supported in: 4
>
> .NET Framework Client Profile Supported in: 4

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you want to stick with .Net 2.0 or 3.5, and avoid having to write ".ToArray()" on the second argument of String.Join(), here's a simple-minded implementation that should mimic the String.Join() implemented in .Net 4.0.

```
   public static class MString
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// This method simply duplicates the String.Join() method that was introduced in .Net 4.0. So
      /// it can be used in C# projects targeting .Net 3.5 or earlier.
      /// </summary>
      /// <typeparam name="T">type of the object collection (typically string)</typeparam>
      /// <param name="separatorString">separator to be placed between the strings</param>
      /// <param name="valueObjects">collection of objects that can be converted to strings</param>
      /// <returns>string containing all of the objects converted to string with separator string in between</returns>
      public static string Join<T>(string separatorString, IEnumerable<T> valueObjects)
      {
         if (separatorString == null)
            separatorString = "";

         bool firstValue = true;
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (T oneObject in valueObjects)
         {
            if (!firstValue)
               stringBuilder.Append(separatorString);
            firstValue = false;

            stringBuilder.Append(oneObject == null ? "" : oneObject.ToString());
         }

         return stringBuilder.ToString();
      }
   }
```